# symbol-name without adding to obarray

Tags: symbols

I found out that querying a symbol's name using `symbol-name` adds the symbol to `obarray`.

```el
(intern-soft "random-name") ; gives nil
(symbol-name 'random-name) ; adds random-name to obarray, gives "random-name" (string).
(intern-soft "random-name") ; gives random-name
```

My concern is that this bloats `obarray` with empty symbols (i.e no value or function definition). Is there

1. something like `symbol-name` which doesn't add the to the obarray?
2. a way to clear the obarray of "useless" (all cells other than the name cell are empty) symbols?

**Edit** -

I just found out that even evaluating a symbol adds it to the `obarray`. So I am assuming this language (or any lisp) is designed in a way that you don't have to worry about the size of `obarray`. Is this correct?

Comment: Have you considered using your own obarray for such operations? `intern-soft` supports that with its optional argument and there's some code making use of that.

Comment: I didn't know that. Does having our own `obarray` have any side effects? For example, do the symbols evaluate like they always do or do we have to explicitly inform to take the symbol from the new `obarray`?

Comment: The lisp reader interns every symbol it encounters, regardless of what it's used for.  You do not have to worry about 'bloat'.

Comment: I wanted to hear that from someone for the sake of assurance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-h f make-symbol`:

> `make-symbol` is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.
>
> `(make-symbol NAME)`
>
> Return a newly allocated uninterned symbol whose name is `NAME`.
>
> Its value is void, and its function definition and property list are `nil`.
> This function does not change global state, including the match data.

And as others have said in comments, you can also intern a symbol in a different obarray.  That doesn't solve your problem of obarray bloating.  But that should be a non-problem anyway.

You use another obarray as a separate namespace.  You can have a symbol `foo` in multiple obarrays.  The symbols are different/separate, with different properties, etc.

You may have an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  If you think so, try to instead ask about something you're really trying to do.

E.g., why do you think you want/need to *"clear the obarray of 'useless' (all cells other than the name cell are empty) symbols"*?

Comment: You're right about the X-Y problem. The thing is, I sometimes don't realise it until someone points it out. About the "why" part, memory management is crucial to a standard language. But I guess that isn't something to be worried about too much in this case.

Comment: Right. No memory management (in the usual sense at least, and in general).